# What would be a good signature for a serialization function?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to design a simple serialization function:

```
    pub fn serialize(buffer: &[u8]) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
        Ok(())
    }
```

the above is not ok because the buffer passed to it could not handle the size for serialization.

What would be a good signature for a serialization function? Should I use a vec?

I'm trying to serialize an RTSP message. It's like HTTP. Not much text, it should be simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a *writer*, designated by the [`std::io::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html) trait.

```
pub fn serialize<W: Write>(writer: &mut W) -> Result<()> {
    writer.write_all(&[1, 2, 3, 4])?;
    Ok(())
}
// or
pub fn serialize(writer: &mut dyn Write) -> Result<()> {
    writer.write_all(&[1, 2, 3, 4])?;
    Ok(())
}
```

This makes it generic over many types that can be used as *"byte-oriented sinks"* like `File`s, `TcpStream`s, and normal `Vec<u8>`s.

```
fn main() {
    let mut buffer = vec![];
    serialize(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", buffer);
}
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

See it running on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f6281291fcb09bd5e8b4a48dac1f256b).